# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-orm, attributeerror

I am writing django application and stuck with the error

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I saw a lot of questions here but no one matches with mine issue.

The issue is with my method in views.py that should return JSON:

```
def get_pattern(request, product_id):
    """
    Get JSON for needed pattern
    """
    data = Patterns.objects.get(related_module=product_id)
    product_data = serializers.serialize("json", [data, ])
    return product_data
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^get_pattern(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_pattern, name='get_pattern'),
```

]

I've tried everything. But when you go /get_pattern1 it returns:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xxxxxxx:8000/xxxx/get_pattern1/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: /home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 31
```

Comment: Do you have any middleware? If you do, show it

Comment: I am guessing `Patterns.objects.get` is not actually where your problem is(assuming you actually have a Patterns model class and are not doing something funny with the objects attribute there) ... do you see any error messages in the console (or apache logs if you are using apache to host)

Comment: No, I don't. It is almost the raw django installation

Comment: do you have debug set to true?\

Comment: @JoranBeasley it returns 500 error to front-end and attributeError when I am trying to access it via browser

Comment: Somewhere you have a method called `process_response`, check inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return product_data
```

A Django view must return an [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) object, not a string.

```
bytes = product_data.encode('utf-8')
return django.http.HttpResponse(bytes, content_type='application/json')
```

(The clickjacking middleware is raising an error because it is assuming the return value from the view is an HttpResponse and calling `get()` on it, but actually it's, erroneously, a `unicode` string.)